# Ray trigonometry in Opengl

Tags: math, opengl-es, perspective

I am quite new to this, and iv'e heard that i need to get my inversed projection matrix and so on to create a ray from a 2D point to a 3D world point, however since im using OpenglES and there are not as many methods as there would be regulary to help me with this. (And i simply don't know how to do it) im using a trigenomeric formula for this insted.

For each time i iterate one step down the negative Z-axis i multiply the Y-position on the screen (-1 to 1) with

> (-z / (cot(myAngle / 2))

And the X position likewise but with a koefficent equally to the aspect ratio.
myAngle is the frustum perspective angle.

This works really good for me and i get very accurate values, so what i wonder is: Why **should** i use the inverse of the projection matrix and multiply it with some stuff **instead** of using this?

Comment: Well after some thinking, i guess it's when the camera comes in to the picture it get's a whole lot different then just this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time you have a matrix lying around for your OpenGl camera.  Using an inverse matrix is simple when you already have a camera matrix on hand.  It is also (oh so very slightly at computer speeds) faster to do a matrix multiply.  And in cases where you are doing a bajillion of these calculations per frame, it can matter.

Here is some good info on getting started on a camera class if you are interested:
[Camera Class](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/reference/programming/140/283/camera-class-tutorial-r1927)

And some [matrix resources](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/reference/programming/math-and-physics/matrices/3d-matrix-math-demystified-r695)

Depending on what you are working on, I wouldn't worry too much about the 'best way to do it.'  You just want to make sure you understand what your code is doing then keep improving it.